# how to replace a \' with '' using sed

Tags: sed

I have a file like this test.sql:

```
'here is' and \' other for 'you'
```

and would like to replace the `\'` (escaped single quote) with `''` (2 singles quotes) for postgres and leave other single quotes alone. How would I do this. I have tried:

```
Mon Mar 16$ sed -i.bak s/\'/''/g test.sql
```

but this takes out all the single quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your enemy in this is shell quoting. The string

```
s/\'/''/g
```

is mangled by the shell before it is given to sed. For the shell, `''` is an empty string, and `\'` suppresses this special meaning of single quotes (so that the quote is an actual single quote character). What sed sees after processing is

```
s/'//g
```

...wich just removes all single quotes.

There are several ways to work around the problem; one of them is

```
sed -i.bak "s/\\\\'/''/g" test.sql
```

Inside the doubly-quoted shell string, backslashes need to be escaped (exceptions exist). This means that `"s/\\\\'/''/g"` in the shell command translates to `s/\\'/''/g` as argument to sed. In sed regexes, backslashes also need escaping, so this is, in fact, what we wanted to happen: All instances of `\'` will be replaced with `''`.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed "s/[\\]'/''/g" test.sql
# also work but may depend on shell
sed "s/[\]'/''/g" test.sql
```

same idea as Wintermute but using class to avoig multi escaping for shell than sed in double quote